# Set Default Tab for Fragment/ViewPager setup

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

How do you set a default tab when the FragmentActivity is first created?  I have 5 tabs and want it to open to tab 2, not 1.  It seems like it should be much easier than it is!

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                    }
                });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }


    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment f = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                f = new MasterFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }


                 // case 1 - 3 edited out; i'd like default view "case 1".

        default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: "
                        + position);
            }

            return f;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.mastercattab1).toUpperCase();

                     // case 1- 3 edited out

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Have you tried calling `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());` at the end of `onCreate()`?

Comment: Close enough, I did `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);` and that worked perfect.

Comment: @Flynny75 not related to this question but can you tell me how i can find that which tab has been selected, so i can perform some actions when a certain tab is selected

Comment: @DawoodAwan I know it's late. You could try `mViewPager.getCurrentItem()`.

Comment: Emphasis on "at the end of", after the listeners. +1

Comment: When I `setCurrentItem` to '0' it loads the first tab. When I set it to `1` it loads the 3rd? any idea why it would do this?

Comment: how to get event of viewpager load??

Comment: @Zapnologica I am facing simillar issue, I have three tabs and the listener for middle fragment never gets called but the listener of other two fragments are called depending on unselected tab. Did you figure out what's happening